# Как составить регулярное выражение для ссылки, содержащей http или https?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно проверить переименую является ли в ней ссылка `http://*` или `https://*`.

Comment: А просто сравнить начало ссылки с подстрокой чем не вариант?

Comment: Есть хорошее правило, "не делай регулярками то, что можно легко сделать функциями работы со строками". Регулярки оч сложно читать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Регулярное выражение

```
/^https?\:\/\//
```

---

#### Пример

```js
alert( /^https?\:\/\//.test('http://example.com') );
```

---

#### Фиддл примера

https://jsfiddle.net/9stdfeks/

---

#### Литература

[Learn.JavaScript.Ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions-javascript)

Comment: Разве тут не обязателен указатель начала строки перед http?

Comment: @Visman, да, можно добавить ... Изменил ответ.